# Python requests html, I do not get the full array in the webpage - url=cmegroup

Tags: python, html-table, beautifulsoup, request

I contact you on a very specific matters for which I struggle to find a solution.
I think it is very specific because it is working with many other website but not on the one I am interested into.

I basically want to find out the value in an array.
If I follow the examples I read over and over, I got this kind of code which is working:

```
import pandas as pd 
import time
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fDf_htmlGetArray():
        #Example of URL found on internet
        str_url = "http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47401&view=1"

        d_headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}  
        o_page = requests.get(str_url, headers = d_headers)
        bs_soup = BeautifulSoup(o_page.content, "html.parser")      
        # I tried as well without success: # lxml   # html5lib

        for o_table in bs_soup.find_all('table'):
            for o_row in o_table.find_all('tr'):
                print('-----row------')
                print(o_row)
                o_ths = [o_th.text.strip() for o_th in o_row.find_all('th')]
                if not o_ths == []:
                    print('-----th------')
                    print(o_ths)            
                o_cells = [o_cell.text.strip() for o_cell in o_row.find_all('td')]
                if not o_cells == []:
                    print('-----cell------')
                    print(o_cells)  
    fDf_htmlGetArray()
```

But the URL I want is :

```
str_url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_futures.html"
```

When I open the webpage and I do INSPECT, I got:

```
<tr class>
 <th scope="row">MAR19</th>
 <td>53.35</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the **td** data obviously.
But When I do the request, I only have the columns name and nothing on td:

```
-----table------
-----row------
<tr>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesMonth" scope="col">Month</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesOpen" scope="col">Open</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesHigh" scope="col">High</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesLow" scope="col">Low</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesLast" scope="col">Last</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesChange" scope="col">Change</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesSettle" scope="col">Settle</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesEstimatedVolume" scope="col">Estimated Volume</th>
<th class="cmeSettlementsFuturesPriorDayOpenInterest" scope="col">Prior Day Open Interest</th>
</tr>
-----th------
['Month', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Last', 'Change', 'Settle', 'Estimated Volume', 'Prior Day Open Interest']
-----row------
<tr>
<td class="cmeTableFoot" colspan="9">
<ul class="cmeLegend">
<li class="cmeSupportingLinks cmeSupportingLinkIcon cmeAboutListIcon"><a href="../../about-settlements.html" rel="popup"><span>About This Report</span></a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
-----cell------
['About This Report']
```

I have tried many other code. I don't know how to settle this.

You are my last hope guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need selenium for this. The reason you are not able to see the `td` tag is b'coz they are populated via an ajax call. Only thing you have to do is to make this call using requests.

We can find this ajax call using the network tab on the inspect tool in your browser while loading the page. We can see that the data is being returned as json.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
date='02/14/2019'
url=f'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/425/FUT?tradeDate={date}'
r= requests.get(url)
df=pd.DataFrame(r.json()['settlements'])
print(df)
```

Output

```
    change    high    last     low   month   open openInterest settle   volume
0     UNCH   54.68   53.58   53.57  MAR 19  53.96      163,621      -  247,818
1     UNCH   55.08   54.02   54.01  APR 19  54.31      346,296      -   95,896
2     UNCH   55.67   54.66  54.64A  MAY 19  54.95      230,913      -   39,197
3     UNCH  56.21B   55.26   55.24  JUN 19  55.43      252,325      -   34,879
4     UNCH  56.64B   55.75   55.75  JLY 19  55.93      136,107      -   14,379
5     UNCH  56.97B   56.17   56.17  AUG 19  56.33       80,681      -    5,624
6     UNCH   57.24  56.46B   56.43  SEP 19  56.58       96,819      -    6,291
7     UNCH   57.35   56.62   56.60  OCT 19  56.78       65,096      -    2,180
8     UNCH  57.45B   56.69   56.65  NOV 19  56.90       51,416      -    2,466
9     UNCH   57.46   56.64   56.62  DEC 19  56.75      189,518      -   15,807
10    UNCH  57.31B  56.84A   56.75  JAN 20  56.75       45,573      -      671
11    UNCH  57.33B   56.78   56.78  FEB 20  57.20       23,674      -      403
12    UNCH  56.69B  56.69B       -  MAR 20      -       50,453      -      744
13    UNCH  56.58B  56.58B       -  APR 20      -       11,320      -       46
14    UNCH       -       -       -  MAY 20      -       10,906      -       29
15    UNCH  56.85B   56.10  56.09A  JUN 20  56.45       60,037      -    2,562
16    UNCH  56.19B   55.98   55.98  JLY 20  55.98        9,515      -       26
17    UNCH       -       -       -  AUG 20      -        6,674      -       22
18    UNCH  55.99B  55.99B       -  SEP 20      -       19,131      -       44
19    UNCH  55.86B  55.86B       -  OCT 20      -        8,727      -        0
20    UNCH  55.77B  55.77B       -  NOV 20      -        7,518      -        0
21    UNCH  56.19B   55.39   55.39  DEC 20  55.75      103,630      -    4,972
22    UNCH       -       -       -  JAN 21      -        8,169      -        0
23    UNCH       -       -       -  FEB 21      -        3,172      -        0
24    UNCH       -       -       -  MAR 21      -        3,816      -        0
25    UNCH       -       -       -  APR 21      -        4,837      -        0
26    UNCH       -       -       -  MAY 21      -        2,702      -        0
27    UNCH   55.39   54.76   54.76  JUN 21  55.22       16,767      -       75
28    UNCH       -       -       -  JLY 21      -        4,621      -        0
29    UNCH       -       -       -  AUG 21      -        2,641      -        0
..     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    ...          ...    ...      ...
79    UNCH       -       -       -  OCT 25      -            0      -        0
80    UNCH       -       -       -  NOV 25      -            0      -        0
81    UNCH       -       -       -  DEC 25      -          201      -        0
82    UNCH       -       -       -  JAN 26      -            0      -        0
83    UNCH       -       -       -  FEB 26      -            0      -        0
84    UNCH       -       -       -  MAR 26      -            0      -        0
85    UNCH       -       -       -  APR 26      -            0      -        0
86    UNCH       -       -       -  MAY 26      -            0      -        0
87    UNCH       -       -       -  JUN 26      -            0      -        0
88    UNCH       -       -       -  JLY 26      -            0      -        0
89    UNCH       -       -       -  AUG 26      -            0      -        0
90    UNCH       -       -       -  SEP 26      -            0      -        0
91    UNCH       -       -       -  OCT 26      -            0      -        0
92    UNCH       -       -       -  NOV 26      -            0      -        0
93    UNCH       -       -       -  DEC 26      -            7      -        0
94    UNCH       -       -       -  JAN 27      -            0      -        0
95    UNCH       -       -       -  FEB 27      -            0      -        0
96    UNCH       -       -       -  MAR 27      -            0      -        0
97    UNCH       -       -       -  APR 27      -            0      -        0
98    UNCH       -       -       -  MAY 27      -            0      -        0
99    UNCH       -       -       -  JUN 27      -            0      -        0
100   UNCH       -       -       -  JLY 27      -            0      -        0
101   UNCH       -       -       -  AUG 27      -            0      -        0
102   UNCH       -       -       -  SEP 27      -            0      -        0
103   UNCH       -       -       -  OCT 27      -            0      -        0
104   UNCH       -       -       -  NOV 27      -            0      -        0
105   UNCH       -       -       -  DEC 27      -            0      -        0
106   UNCH       -       -       -  JAN 28      -            0      -        0
107   UNCH       -       -       -  FEB 28      -            0      -        0
108                                  Total           2,074,304         475,282

[109 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Hello,This is working perfectly well. Can you please remind me how do find this URL address ? I will have more website like this. How did you find  
 
 
 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/425/FUT?tradeDate={date}'        from       "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_futures.html"

Comment: @LaurentT You can use the chrome *Network tab in the chrome dev* tools. Go to the website, open the network tab and refresh the page.  You will see a lot of requests. You can select `xhr` on the top to see only the ajax requests. If you select one with `FUT?strategy=...` you should be able to see the url in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_futures.html')

page = browser.page_source

cme_tables = pd.read_html(page)
```

You need to use Selenium because the prices are generated dynamically with JavaScript. Dynamically generated content cannot be scraped with tools like `requests` or panda's `read_html()` method.

Here is a link to the Selenium [python api](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html).

---

Comment: I have tried already this method by the way.
As I said, it is a very specific question and I have tried many ways including this one.

Thanks

Comment: I got the error:

...
  File "C:\Users\XXX \AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 749, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

  File "C:\Users\XXX \AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 385, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
HTTPError: Forbidden

Comment: Please check my edit. You will need to use Selenium.